# Command-line Parameters in C program?

Tags: c, parameters

How do I read command-line parameters in C? For example, in

```
./test --help
```

or

```
./test --build
```

how do I access "--build" or "--help"?

Comment: the command line parameters are part of your main function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your parameters are in argv:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

if you printf the content of argv (argv[0],argv[1] etc) youll get the idea.

try:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(int i = 0;i< argc;i++) 
        printf("%s\r\n",argv[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `argc` and `argv` arguments to the `main` function and do different things based on them:

```
#include <string.h>
void dohelp(void) { /* whatever; */ }
void dobuild(void) { /* whatever; */ }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) dohelp();
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "--build")) dobuild();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`argc` contains the number of parameters passed by the shell to your program, including the program name. So `myapp --help` gets an argc of 2.

`argv` are the arguments themselves. The last argv (`argv[argc]`) is the NULL pointer.

---

Edit: the parameters don't need to be named `argc` and `argv`, but naming else something else is **very, very** bad!

```
int main(int foo, char **bar) /* RGAGGGGHH */
int main(int n, char **options) /* RGAGGGGHH */
```

Comment: If strcmp returns true (e.g. doesn't match) then it says segmentation fault?

Comment: There's a `!` before the strcmp to make it match

Comment: Thanks! Just what in needed. although <string.h> doesn't need to be included for strcmp just stdio.h

Comment: *`/* RGAGGGGHH */`* Don't hold back. Tell us what you *really* think.

Comment: @Daniel: The declaration for `strcmp()` lives in `string.h`. `stdio.h` just happens to include `string.h`. It doesn't hurt to include both `string.h` and `stdio.h`, but that's what I would do.

Comment: Ok but how would i get the value of a parameter? i guess split anything past "=" ?

Comment: @Daniel: have a look at [Matthieu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280131/command-line-parameters-in-c-program/5280151#5280151). The [advanced getopt](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) does it all. Otherwise you'll have to break the options apart on the `=` sign and treat each part separately; pay attention to whitespace (`-t 1` vs `-t=1` vs `-t = 1` vs ...) and deal with `argv` carefully yourself. **(getopt can be a bitch too)**

Comment: @pmg how would i detect if they didn't enter an option?

Comment: @Daniel: by the value of `argc`. It is `1` if only the program name was typed; `2` if there was one paramter; `3` with the program name and 2 parameters; ...

Answer (score 2):

The very basic is to use the arguments `(int argc, char *argv[])` and you can parse those directly.

One more advanced method is to use getopt... http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

Answer (score 2):

Command line arguments are arguments passed to your program with its name. For example, the UNIX program `cp` (copies two files) has the following command line arguments:

`cp SOURCE DEST`

You can access the command line arguments with `argc` and `argv`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

argc is the number of arguments, including the program name, and argv is the array of strings containing the arguments. `argv[0]` is the program name, and `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be a `NULL` pointer.

So the `cp` program can be implemented as such:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *src = argv[1];
    char *dest = argv[2];

    cpy(dest, src);
}
```

They do not have to be named `argc` and `argv`; they can have any name you want, though traditionally they are called that.

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to do it [as usual].
Command line arguments are read from argv (passed to main along with argc).

You can parse those yourself and have a bit switch setting flags each time a new option is found in argv. Or you can use a library to parser command line arguments. I suggest libc getopt (google it).