# My program won't read or write to the .txt when it did previously

Tags: c++

I was developing the beginnings of a chatbot a while back and I decided to put some more progress into it tonight, however, when I tried to get it to read or write to it's "brain.txt" it won't do so.

I remember it being able to do this previously, as the "brain.txt" I have has 8 entries in it that came from the chatbot itself.

Could anyone look over my code or tell me what's up? thanks.

also any minor code suggestions would be awesome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>


using namespace std;

//prototypes
int main();
string UserTalk();
void BotRespond(string x);
void BotComprehend(string x);
void BotRemember(string x);
void write(string area, string input);
tuple<bool, int> BotRecollect(string userinput);
//                     


//PLAN

//the user should be able to say anything, like a greeting.
//the bot should be able to either understand that it is a greeting and respond accordingly.
//for the bot to understand sit is a greeting, it should be marked as a greeting, somehow.
//OR it says it doesn't understand and will want to add the new spoken word to it's brain.
//when asking for the new word the bot will take in the word itself, and it's use (greeting, goodbye, joke etc)


int main()
{
    cout << "What would you like me to remember?" << endl;
    BotRemember(UserTalk());
    return 0;
}



string UserTalk()
{
    //simply gets user input.
    string x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

tuple<bool, int> BotRecollect(string userinput)
{   
    //moves the brain into memories
    //if the user input matches a memory.
    int filepos = 0;
    string memories;
    ifstream brain ("projects/AI/brain.txt");
    if (brain.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(brain,memories))
        {
            if (memories.find(userinput) != string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "I know that already!" << endl;
                    brain.close();
                    return make_tuple(true, filepos);
                }
            else { filepos++; }
        }
            brain.close();
            return make_tuple(false, filepos);
    }
}

void BotRemember(string userinput)
{
        //remembers the input as a new memory if it's new.
        //the alternative would be it knows it already.

    const char *c;  


        tuple<bool, int> memory = BotRecollect(userinput);

        if (!get<0>(memory))
        {   
                cout << "I didn't know that.";
                string d = to_string(get<1>(memory)).c_str();
                string e = userinput.c_str();
                write("brain", d + " " + e);
        }
}

void write(string area, string userinput)
{
    ofstream x;
    x.open ("projects/AI/" + area + ".txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    x << userinput << endl;
    x.close();
}
void BotRespond(string x)
{

}
```

Here is the data in it's current "brain.txt"

```
0 suspect
1 interest
2 underwood
3 interior
4 bullet
5 dog
6 grapefruit
7 aliens
8 trump
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, while observing the values of the variables?

Comment: I'm currently using NppExec and MinGW on NP++ so I don't really have a debugger that could do this unless I moved to VS.

Comment: Maybe the path is invalid.

Comment: `tuple<bool, int> BotRecollect(string userinput)` has undefined behavior when a file is not found. I mean what does it return?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be though there IS a brain.txt in projects/AI/...

Comment: Maybe your current folder when executing your program was is not the same as it was. I mean perhaps there is no projects folder in the current working directory.

Comment: ***I don't really have a debugger that could do this unless I moved to VS.*** Back 25+ years ago when I did not have a debugger (and submitted my code via a batch job on a unix machine) I used a lot of print statements..

Comment: @StrayProg [VS is not the one and only debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_debuggers). Don't limit yourself with thinking that it is.

Comment: now it won't even compile. 

to_string isn't defined, what the hell.

Comment: In addition: `projects/AI/brain.txt` seems like a _relative_ path. Are you sure, that the folder is there _relative_ to the application you are trying to run?

Comment: *I'm not sure why it would be though there IS a brain.txt in projects/AI/*  -- If the file can't be found, then you have to return something -- the code's behavior is undefined if the file isn't found.  Also, never write programs thinking that nothing will go wrong.  Checking for file existence and acting upon a file that doesn't exist isn't something that should be left out or "left for later".  Output a message and return a default constructed tuple if you have to.

Comment: how would I turn the relative path into something more permanent? also I fixed the compile issue. 

I'll put in a return.

Comment: I added a return if the brain wasn't open, just an else to the if(brain.is_open()) so it turns out it's not open, which means it's not finding the file.

Comment: fixed it, this is a problem with paths, could anyone give me a solution to fix the path issue to make it more dynamic? it couldn't find the file to read or write, I added a more hardcoded path, so now it only works for me

Comment: also just found a debugger for np++, i'll install it later.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/?source=typ_redirect

Comment: ***to fix the path issue to make it more dynamic?*** Make the path a command line parameter to your program.

Comment: what does that mean, sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280131/command-line-parameters-in-c-program

Comment: An alternate way is to ask the user at the start of the program.